# List more than 1000 Buckets with XML API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

[GET Service for listing Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-service)

With the tutorial in the link above, I am able to list Buckets in my account. However, the response only return 1000 Buckets which I believe is the limit for a single response. The problem is how can I list the remaining Buckets in my account? For listing Bucket Objects, we can add the marker param to indicate from which object to continue listing but it seems there is no such param for listing Buckets.

**Edit:**

I am using HMAC keys instead of OAuth2 to make request so I cannot use the JSON API, "HMAC keys can only be used to make requests to the XML API, not the JSON API", according to [HMAC keys Restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/hmackeys#restrictions)

Current XML response which doesn't include anything like marker, cursor or pageToken:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ListAllMyBucketsResult
    xmlns='http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01'>
    <Buckets>
        <Bucket>
            <Name>bucket-1</Name>
            <CreationDate>2019-09-23T07:03:11.892Z</CreationDate>
        </Bucket>
        <Bucket>
            <Name>bucket-2</Name>
            <CreationDate>2019-09-23T07:03:12.578Z</CreationDate>
        </Bucket>
        ...
        <Bucket>
            <Name>bucket-999</Name>
            <CreationDate>2019-09-23T07:03:11.892Z</CreationDate>
        </Bucket>
        <Bucket>
            <Name>bucket-1000</Name>
            <CreationDate>2019-09-23T07:03:12.578Z</CreationDate>
        </Bucket>
  </Buckets>
</ListAllMyBucketsResult>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [JSON API's](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list) list method. With this method whenever your results are over the maximum a `pageToken` item will be returned, you can use it as a parameter for your next request in order to paginate through the results.

Before implementing it you can [test this API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list?apix=true) from the documentation page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The JSON api works but since I am using HMAC keys instead of OAuth2, JSON api is not an option.

Comment: In that case could you edit your question with what you have so far and how the response looks like?

Comment: Thank you for the edit @BonBon . I work for the GCP Support team and I got in touch with the Cloud Storage engineering team to clarify this situation, the team said that this is the expected behaviour. The XML API will list up to 1,000 buckets. I've created an internal ticket to update the documentation in order to avoid this kind of situations.

Comment: And even though when listing objects it is possible to add the marker param, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-bucket-list) specifies that the XML API does not return lists longer that 1,000 objects.